# URI String Manipulation in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, uri

My question is simple, I need to turn this

"devlxxx/mxxxxxxxxx/xxx.asmx" into this "devlxxxmxxxxxxxxxxxx".

The catch is that, In my application a user submits a webservice, I save the URI as a string and take its

```
    uri.Host + uri.PathAndQuery
```

and set that as a new string. This leaves me with "devlxxx/mxxxxxxxxx/xxx.asmx". The Web service URI can be any length in size so the length is not Constant. My first theoretical approach was to remove the slashes by interating over the string and removing them whereever they occured. Regardless the final out put should return the first part of the URI (before the first forward slash) and the second part of the url (text between the first forward slash and the second), and removing the rest of the text..... Any theories of code snippits would be much appreciated.

Comment: If a string.replace("/", "") can't solve it than I can't understand your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way can be to remove `/` and then use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`.

```
string str = "devlxxx/mxxxxxxxxx/xxx.asmx";
str = str.Replace("/", "");
string requiredStr = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str);
```

and you will get: `requiredStr = "devlxxxmxxxxxxxxxxxx"`

Although its not exactly a file name but this trick should do the work.

Comment: @Cemafor, yes its shorter, but I would leave the code for clarity :)

Comment: I actually added that before you added a code sample, or at least before my browser decided to show it. Ill remove my comment :)

Comment: Yup it works, See, This is Why I need to Read more API Documentation, i was unaware of the GetFileNameWithoutExtension();

Comment: @habib, I use this as a means to name the text file in which the webservice is being saved... And then display this in a Recent URI list box to allow the user to select a recent URI to load in the WEb Service Application.